# Scala/Java - Parsing the String which only has date part

Tags: java, scala

So I have 2 strings

```
val a : String = "foo April 06 1994 bar"
val b : String = "April 06 1994" // this format can change
```

and I have a seq of 4 parsers

```
private val dateParsers = Seq(
    JChronicDateParser,
    UKDateParser,
    USDateParser,
    GermanDateParser
  )
```

and now I parse them variables I get succesful results in both cases

```
dateParsers.map(parsers => {
            parsers.parse(variable)//a or b
          })
```

Is there any efficient way to fail the parsing of the `string a`, I want parsers to fail when there's any extra info or characters in the string with the date part?

I have tried methods like not using any parser rather getting the string in and formatting it with

```
val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
dateFormat.parse(a) // it fails in both cases so no good
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `SimpleDateFormat` fails because the format you give it is wrong. 
Try `"MMMM dd yyyy"`.

Also, `SimpleDateFormat` isn't a very good option. Since java 8, it's better to use `DateTimeFormatter` instead:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd yyyy").parse("April 06 1994")
```

As to your other question - "Is there any efficient way to fail the parsing of the string a" - I have no idea what you are asking ... Throw exception? Return an `Option`? a `Try`?

Comment: Thanks this does what I wanted to do.